# sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame, put data label inside of chart

Tags: charts, sapui5

Does someone know how to put data label inside of donut (sap.viz.ui5.controls.Vizframe)? It was possible with sap.viz.ui5.Donut.. but I cant find a solution for this one :( It is outside of plotArea per default and it doesn't look good:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q5cJ.png]

I'd appreciate an answer!

Comment: The only solution I have found back then was to change back the sapui5 version in run configurations